How can I skip/disable running of unittests in rustc bootstrap build testing?
I am running rustc bootstrap build tests via the commandline:
python3 src/bootstrap/bootstrap.py test --exclude "some excluded test cases list" --no-fail-fast --bless --target x86_64-poky-linux-gnu

Which give failures as follows:
Running unittests src/lib.rs (/home/build-st/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/rust/1.77.0/rustc-1.77.0-src/build

/bootstrap/debug/deps/bootstrap-fca753a60bf3f353)
uploaded "/home/build-st/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/rust/1.77.0/rustc-1.77.0-src/build/bootstrap/debug/deps/bootstrap-fca753a60bf3f353", waiting for result
thread 'main' panicked at src/tools/remote-test-client/src/main.rs:310:9:
client.read_exact(&mut header) failed with failed to fill whole buffer
note: run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display a backtrace
error: test failed, to rerun pass --lib
error: test failed, to rerun pass --bin bootstrap
error: test failed, to rerun pass --bin rustc
error: test failed, to rerun pass --bin rustdoc
error: test failed, to rerun pass --bin sccache-plus-cl

error: 5 targets failed:
--lib
--bin bootstrap
--bin rustc
--bin rustdoc
--bin sccache-plus-cl

Since these unit tests give build failures, how can I skip/disable them (all unittest cases) from running using the above command (any flag or option to be passed) so that the build is completed successfully.
Until Rust 1.75 unit tests were not executed since we were using --doc option in the command. But, from Rust 1.76 we dropped that option as it didn't run any tests (unit test and integration tests) on cross-targets.
After this, many of the unittest cases failed as above.
What can be the reason for this?
As a work around, how can I disable/skip execution of all unittest cases? Is there any commandline flag/option to do so?
I know about the #[ignore] attribute but it's not feasible to do as there are many files.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-test.html#target-selection

@cafce25, how should I modify the above command (python3 src/bootstrap/bootstrap.py test --exclude "some excluded test cases list" --no-fail-fast --bless --target x86_64-poky-linux-gnu) with the options mentioned in the document so that the unittests are not executed.
I want use cmd since I am running the tests automatically with a script.

Explicitly add the tests you do want to run. Or set test = false in Cargo.toml for the unit's you don't want tested by default.

Is there any way to do same with command line flags/options?

test = false no, explicitly adding, yes, see the documentation

@cafce25,
I added the following lines to set in Cargo.toml file(this is src/tools/tidy/Cargo.toml file)
[[bin]]  name = "rust-tidy"
path = "src/main.rs"

test = false

+[lib]
+test = false
but still see the following failure:

Running unittests src/lib.rs (build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/stage0-bootstrap-tools/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/tidy-268e857e44aa5cf1)

thread 'main' panicked at src/tools/remote-test-client/src/main.rs:310:9:
client.read_exact(&mut header) failed with failed to fill whole buffer

error: test failed, to rerun pass --lib```

Same error is seen with src/main.rs file also.
